# Codepen pug and data from javascript

Tags: pug, javascript-objects, codepen

I'm trying to use [Codepen](https://codepen.io/TrasherDK/pen/moxJNe) for some prototyping.

I can't figure out, how to get a `javascript` object into a `pug template`.

- The object

```js
const User = {
  name: 'TrasherDK',
  auth: {
    login: 'trasherdk',
    token: 'sha512'
  },
  validated: 1
}
```

- The template

```
  +nav_section_right
    if (! User.validated)
      +nav_item_glyph("#register", "user", " Sign Up")
      +nav_item_glyph("#login", "log-in", " Log in")
    else
      +nav_item_glyph("#profile", "user", "#{User.name}")
```

That gives me `Cannot read property 'validated' of undefined`

Then I added `script const User = #{User}` to the top of the `pug template`.

That also gives me `Cannot read property 'validated' of undefined`

Then I added a function to `javascript`

```js
function getData() {
  return User;
}
```

and changed the `pug template` to:

```
script const User = #{getData()};
```

Which in turn results in `getData is not a function`.

At this point I ran out of ideas to try. Google didn't help either.

Comment: I know @sean is on the right trail, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript pane in Codepen is just for client-side javascript. Pug has no access to it when compiling. If you want to use a JSON object in your Pug on Codepen, you'll need to add it to the Pug/HTML pane as a variable, above your other code that references it.

The best way to do this is to add it as [block unbuffered code](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html), where you add a hyphen and the indent the code beneath it:

```
-
  const User = {
    name: 'TrasherDK',
    auth: {
      login: 'trasherdk',
      token: 'sha512'
    },
    validated: 1
  }

// the rest of your pug code goes here
```

Comment: This is the only way to do it in a Codepen pen.

Comment: I know @sean is on the right track, but...  I would like to have run my stuff in `js` berfore pug.render... but I guess, you can't have it all..

Comment: Again, not possible on Codepen.